# Verifying long-range dependency in multi-variate time series

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, autocorrelation, long-range-dependence

I am fairly new to the area of time series and I am trying to understand the notion of long-range dependence in time series. My goal is to characterize the same in the case of multi-variate time series. The [Wikipedia page on long-range dependence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-range_dependence) talks about using some second-order statistics such as auto-covariance, partial sums etc,. for detecting long-term memory. Is there any way these methods can be generalized to multi-variate case, i.e at each time $t$, my time series value $x_t \in \mathbb{R}^d$?

Is there an agreed notion of how to test long-range dependency even for scalar valued time series?